# Spring JPA bi-directional cannot evaluate toString

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have resolved JSON recursive loop with `@JsonIdentityInfo`through to Baeldung's blog[1](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) (Thanks)

But now, another error occurs :

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.mezoo.tdc.model.Payment.toString()
```

Here my Registration object :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Registration")
    @JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
    public class Registration implements Serializable {

       /*some private variables..*/

      // Bidirectional relationship
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="registration", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private List<Payment> payment;

                @Override
      public String toString() {
         return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("payment", payment)
            .toString();
         }
    }
```

Now, Payment object :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Payment")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
    public class Payment implements Serializable {
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "registration")
       private Registration registration;

       @Override
       public String toString() {
       return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("registration", registration)
            .toString();
       }
    }
```

This is, what I see in debugger :

[image: debug screenshot]

Please, what is wrong and why ?

Comment: It's only a IDE's error (warning)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, my guess is that `Registration.toString()` prints the string representation of each payment in the list, and since `Payment.toString()` includes the string representation of `Registration`, `Registration.toString()` is called again, which in turn calls `Payment.toString()` again, and so on.

Try to return an empty string in `Payment.toString()` to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Returning an empty string resolved the issue. however, it means that the toString method is now redundant. Can this issue be fixed with a better JPA mapping configuration? I am using the Lombok @Data annotation for the toString method, could that cause the issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `@Data` implies `@ToString`, which grabs all the fields of the class and prints them in `toString()`. So yes, it's quite likely `@Data` is the issue here. As for the mapping, unless you feel you don't need a bidirectional association, there's nothing to be improved, it's perfectly valid. It's the way `toString()` is generated that's causing problems.

Comment: Lombok supports exclduing single field from being added to automatically generated toString() method. Add `@ToString.Exclude` annotation on the field, which You want to exclude from the automatically generated toString() method.

Comment: I know this is old, however I had this on an repository query on an object that had only multiple OneToOne relationships.  The solution was to eliminate @Data and use just Setters Getters RequiredArgsConstructor. hth.

Answer (score 94):

Remove `toString` method.

*In case you are using Lombok:*

Check you Entity/DAO class you might be using `@Data` annotation from **lombok** which by default includes getter and setters. Change it to `@Getters` and `@Setter` in case you need those and **remove `@Data`** annotation.

Comment: I was using @Data annotation and removed it and changed it to _@Getters_ and _@Setters_ and it fixed. thanks

Comment: Exactly what I'm lookin' for.

Comment: Instead of changing the `@Data` annotation, 
You can replace the area causing the error with `@ToString.Exclude`.

Comment: @Fatih another great alternative

Comment: That's the answer!

Comment: You haven't explained why #toString causes the exception.

Answer (score 4):

in your `Registration.toString()` you are calling a `Payment.toString()` and on your `Payment.toString()` you are calling `Registration.toString()`

You have created a loop in toString

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
        .add("payment", payment) //<----------- REMOVE THIS
        .toString();
  }
```

or

```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
   return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
        .add("registration", registration) //<----------- REMOVE THIS
        .toString();
   }
```

**Or better... remove both**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `lombok` then you can exclude mapping from toString() as follows,

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="Registration")
    @JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
@ToString(exclude = {"payment"})
    public class Registration implements Serializable {
..
..
..Your code
}
```

Same for payment entity.