# Database reference problem causing Fail-safe cleanup loop in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

Like in the subject, I have a problem with Hibernate. I would like to add an item to my set, but as I guess my Movie object has a reference to the Director object in it, which causes loops between these items. It gives me a Fail-safe cleanup. What can I do to get rid of the problem? Below is my code:

USER ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
        })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    private Date creationDate;

    @NotBlank
    private byte[] profileImage;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "movie_to_watch",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"))
    private Set<Movie> moviesToWatch = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MOVIE ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long movieId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "director_id")
        private Director director;

        @NotBlank
        private String title;

        @NotBlank
        private String description;

        @NotBlank
        private Date releaseDate;

        @NotBlank
        private Long length;

        @NotBlank
        private String posterImagePath;

        @NotBlank
        private String backgroundImagePath;

        @NotBlank
        private double globalRating;

        @NotBlank
        private Date addingDate;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable( name = "movie_categories",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
        private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

DIRECTOR ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table( name = "directors")
public class Director {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long directorId;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank
    private String nationality;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "director",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Line of code that generates the problem:

```
user.getMoviesToWatch().add(movie);
userRepository.save(user);
```

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17XGJ.png)

Thanks to everyone for the hints and tips :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JPA bi-directional cannot evaluate toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266770/spring-jpa-bi-directional-cannot-evaluate-tostring)

Comment: Look also at [this article](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/). As here suggested: *You probably don’t want to use Data annotation with Entity classes but rather only use the Getter and Setter methods and implement your own equals, hashCode and toString methods.*

Comment: As it turns out, it actually helped. I had to remove '@Data' and add '@getter' '@setter' in its place. The problem is gone automatically. Thanks