# Spring JPA - Find by join table column - SOLVED

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have following two tables:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DiscountContract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long id;
    private String extReferenceId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contract_type_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ContractType contractType;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContractType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long id;
    private String type;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

}
```

I would like to write SPeL query to find out the records based on `extReferenceId` from the main (`DiscountContract`) table and `type` from the join table(`ContractType`) table

I tried with this query `findDiscountContractByExtReferenceIdAndContractTypeType("12343212", "test")` but facing this issue

> Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate java.util.Optional.toString()

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Although it's not JPA related, I will leave the question, as it can help other people to find a way to make this join query

The problem was related to the `Lombok` annotation @Data and `toString()` that come out of the box from it. `toString()` method causes circular calls of both objects.

To summarize, I removed the `@Data` annotation from the Entity models and replace it with `@Getter` & `@Setter`

More details can be found in this post - [spring-jpa-bi-directional-cannot-evaluate-tostring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266770/spring-jpa-bi-directional-cannot-evaluate-tostring)